# Can not check input number in SQL plus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have an example which input number in form of oracle sql plus, and here is my code :

```
DECLARE 
    WK_INPUT NUMBER := &NUMBER;
BEGIN
    IF WK_INPUT IS NOT NUMBER THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('IS NOT NUMBER')
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(WK_INPUT ||' IS NUMBER')
    END IF;
END;
```

When I execute it has error:

```
 Encounter the symbol 'Number' when expecting the of the flow.
```

how can I check the input is number or not ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "NUMBER" function in Oracle.  You don't really need it here, however, because when you declare the variable WK_INPUT to be of type NUMBER, you can only assign a number to it or else you'll get an exception.  You could write this:

```
DECLARE
  wk_input NUMBER;
BEGIN
  wk_input := '&NUMBER';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(wk_input||' is a number');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('&NUMBER is not a number');
END;
```

Comment: As above you can also do a to_number then catch the exception

Comment: Putting `&NUMBER` in the script twice means two inputs are needed.  Using `&&NUMBER` would mean no prompt when re-running the script.

Comment: I just used DEFINE in my script.  No inputs needed at all :-)